# Tile And A Place - Where Have The Leaders Gone?

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Each circle represents an (as yet) unknown category.

Each of the six tiles belongs to at least one category.

One tile has been placed. Where do the other tiles go and why?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a stab at the solution:

> ISRAELI, HATCHER, and EEL are in the left oval. HAUNT and REFUGE are in the right oval. DEN and LAIR are in the overlapping section.

This is because:

> DEN, LAIR, HAUNT, and REFUGE are all synonyms referring to a place you can stay / hang out (or perhaps more aptly, they are a place you can go or be taken to - "Where have the leaders gone?" "Take me to your leader").
>
> And DEN, LAIR, ISRAELI, HATCHER, and EEL can all be turned into the name of a British Prime Minister by prepending a letter to the word:  Anthony **E**DEN, Tony **B**LAIR, Benjamin **D**ISRAELI, Margaret **T**HATCHER, and Robert **P**EEL.  Here "leader" hints both to the government position and the leading letter of the name.

Comment: Well done on the answer SQLnoob - and also noticing my thinly veiled overuse of the "leader" motif!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the desired solution as it is not exactly wordplay nor it applies the title, but is a solution nonetheless:

> Left oval:   DEN REFUGE EEL
>
> Overlapping: ISRAELI HATCHER
>
> Right oval:  LAIR HAUNT

Because:

> The left oval contains words containing the letter E, the right one the letter A.